# How to drag rows from one DataTable to another? (PrimeVue)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuedraggable, primevue

I'm trying to drag rows from one [DataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/datatable) to another. This [animation](https://i.imgur.com/1pE54cQ.mp4) shows what I try to achieve, kind off.

But from the looks of it PrimeVue doesn't seem to support this, or at least I can't figure out why.

Plan B is to use [vue.draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) but seeing as I cannot isolate a child row-item from the datatable, I don't think I can wrap it in a draggable component.

The code used in the animation:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-content-center gap-4">
    <DataTable :value="cars1" @row-reorder="onRowReorder">
      <Column :rowReorder="true" headerStyle="width: 3em" />
      <Column field="brand" header="brand"></Column>
      <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
    </DataTable>

    <DataTable :value="cars2" @row-reorder="onRowReorder">
      <Column :rowReorder="true" headerStyle="width: 3em" />
      <Column field="brand" header="brand"></Column>
      <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const cars1 = ref([
  { brand: "BMW", color: "Green" },
  { brand: "Volvo", color: "Yellow" },
  { brand: "Audi", color: "Red" },
  { brand: "Ford", color: "Pink" }
]);
const cars2 = ref([]);

function onRowReorder(event) {
  const draggedCar = cars1.value[event.dragIndex]
  cars2.value.push(draggedCar);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build it yourself by using `@vueuse`'s `useDropZone` utility function and by using the template in the column of the reorder icon.

That way you stil use PrimeVue's dragging logic, but you can intercept it yourself with `mousedown` and `mouseup` events in combination with the `onDrop` callback of the `useDropZone` utility function. See snippet below.

```
<template>
  <div class="flex">
    <DataTable :value="cars1">
      <Column :rowReorder="true" headerStyle="width: 3em">
        <template #body="{ index, data }">
          <i
            @mousedown="onHandleClick(index, data)"
            @mouseup="clearHandle"
            :class="['p-datatable-reorderablerow-handle', 'pi pi-bars']"
          ></i>
        </template>
      </Column>
      <Column field="brand" header="brand"></Column>
      <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
    </DataTable>

    <DataTable ref="dropzoneTable" :value="cars2">
      <Column :rowReorder="true" headerStyle="width: 3em" />
      <Column field="brand" header="brand"></Column>
      <Column field="color" header="Color"></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const cars1 = ref([
  { brand: 'BMW', color: 'Green' },
  { brand: 'Volvo', color: 'Yellow' },
  { brand: 'Audi', color: 'Red' },
  { brand: 'Ford', color: 'Pink' },
]);
const cars2 = ref([]);

const dropzoneTable = ref();
const { isOverDropzone } = useDropZone(dropzoneTable, onDrop);

const draggingRow = ref();

function onHandleClick(index, data) {
  draggingRow.value = data;
}

function onDrop() {
  cars2.value.push(draggingRow.value);
}

function clearHandle() {
  draggingRow.value = null;
}
</script>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-pp7mdb?file=app.vue

Comment: Nice and simple alternative to vue.draggable, thanks!